# How to delete the oldest child in Firebase JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I want to limit the amount of data in my Firebase app by deleting the oldest child of a list every time a new one is added. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: So that's what you _want_, but what's your _question_?

Comment: The question is the title, the description is what I want. Sorry about that.

Comment: I strongly advice you reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Triforcey so why don't you add it to your description? You can edit that.

Comment: Sorry about my question being unclear, I wrote this at a younger age.

Comment: I edited the question. I'd appreciate it if you'd remove your down votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So every time a child is added, you want to delete the oldest child from that same list?

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://your.firebaseio.com/children');
ref.on('child_added', function(newSnapshot) {
  ref.limitToLast(1).once('child_added', function(oldestSnapshot) {
    oldestSnapshot.ref().remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! No matter where I looked, I couldn't find an answer.